# array into function C

Tags: c, arrays, function

This is a simple code that i've written because i need a confirmation about a thing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void pr(int a);

int main(void)
{
  int a;

  printf("starting...\n");
  h1:
  scanf("%d", &a);
  if (a == 20)
    return 0;
  pr(a);
  goto h1;
  printf("ending...\n");
  return 0;
}

void pr(int a)
{
  char buf[256];
  if (a == 1)
    strcpy(buf, "number 1 has been choosed");
  else
    strcpy(buf, "other number");
  printf("BUF: %s\n", buf);
}
```

My question is:
Every time the function `pr` is called, the array `buf` is automatically cleared or it is more secure to do a `memset` before the function end?

Comment: Is "doubt" used like "question" in India?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> every time the function pr is called, the array buf is automatically cleared

No, it will contain undefined data since it has automatic storage. The simplest would be to:

```
char buf[256] = {0}; /* Zeroes entire array. */
```

Or, since you're using `buf` as a string, you could go with the cheaper:

```
char buf[256];
buf[0] = 0;
```

---

Side note: the way your code looks you don't need this initialization since `strcpy` doesn't depend on it and you have a `strcpy` on each branch.

Comment: Can i ask you why you do this if the array is a char array?? :)

Comment: @polslinux You're asking about `buf[0] = 0` ? It's the convention that in C "strings" are 0-terminated char arrays. So as long as you're using them right you shouldn't care what lies past `0`.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not cleared, the contents are indeterminate.

The easiest thing to do, given that you're using it as a C string (a sequence of characters terminated by the zero character), is to simply set the initial character to zero:

```
char buf[256];
*buf = '\0';
```

The `buf` variable is an automatic storage duration object and the relevant part of the standard is `C11, 6.2.4 Storage durations of objects, para 6`:

> For such an object that does not have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from entry into the block with which it is associated until execution of that block ends in any way. (Entering an enclosed block or calling a function suspends, but does not end, execution of the current block.) If the block is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created each time. **The initial value of the object is indeterminate. If an initialization is specified for the object, it is performed each time the declaration is reached in the execution of the block; otherwise, the value becomes indeterminate each time the declaration is reached.**